# Main index route is working, all others are not

Tags: express

Can anyone help me figure out why my express routes arent working please. I have been stuck for days trying to figure this out but I keep getting 404 errors when I got to any of the routes in customer.js

<--------------------main server-------------->

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var ordersRouter = require('./routes/orders');
var customersRouter = require('./routes/customers');
var productsRouter = require('./routes/products');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/customers', customersRouter);
app.use('/orders', ordersRouter);
app.use('/products', productsRouter);

app.listen(80);
module.exports = app;
```

### one of my route files below the only route file works is the index router.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();



router.get('/customers', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.status())
res.send('<p>some html</p>');

});
router.post('/customers/update/shipping', function(req, res) {
res.send('<p>someg html</p>');
});
router.post('/customers/update/billing', function(req, res) {
res.send('<p>somew html</p>');
});
router.post('/customers/update/cart', function(req, res) {
res.send('<p>some dhtml</p>');
});

module.exports = router;
```

<------------------------------------------------------>

Answer (score 1):

In your customers files your routes will already be relative to `/customers`. remove the leading `/customers` from all your routes. For e.g:

```
router.get('/customers', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.status())
    res.send('<p>some html</p>');
});
```

Should just be

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.status())
    res.send('<p>some html</p>');
});
```

same principle applies for the other files.

Comment: wow! thank you so much Mr. Mkantjwa!!!! you are a life saver!!!. it's a school assignment that's due today, have been stuck for days.

Comment: hey sorry, one more question, the other customer routes arent working when I remove /customers

Comment: Note that the others are POST requests. So be sure that you are are `POST`ing to your API. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is pretty good for that. If they do not need to be post requests then you can simply change them to `router.get`'s

Comment: As a courtesy, please accept his answer if it did help you !